# Organizing a Visual Studio Solution for two similar products

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

We have a VS2010 Solution which contains one windows form application and 4 Class Library (DLL) projects.  (The class libraries are things like BusinessTier, DataTier, CommonCode, ControlLibrary) The whole thing is targeted for framework 2.0.  Its been like this for three years.

Ok

So our application has grown to the point where we want to add a large new feature and marketing wants to deploy it as a separate product.  Our product is used to fill in tax forms and the second product will fill in other tax forms.

We want to end up with two exe's (two install MSIs) which will be sold/installed/updated independently and could both be run at the same time on the same computer.  Most of the code is in common between the two apps.

I am trying to figure out the best way to structure the solution to create the desired outcome.

1) Option one could be to create a new EXE project and several new DLL projects in the same original solution (Say in a solution folder) which have unique names,versions, guids, etc. with most of the code files as links back to the code files in the original similar DLLS.   This allows us to have two completly separate systems with unique names for all the files, version numbers, etc., but allow any customization to be made to each project/dll.  Is this a good idea or overkill?

2) Option two would be to create a new exe project in the solution and link to the same dlls as the first exe project.   This seems simple enough, but i do not know if it is a good idea to have two projects which use the same DLLs.    I do not really want to use the GAC.  If we have two exe's which use the same Dll's ( even though they will be in separate application folders) with there be a problem if the DLLS have the same/different  version numbers, name or GUID?

What are your ideas?

How should i restructure the solution to accommodate the new product?

Answer (score 1):

Go for Option 2

There is no problem with the same Dlls with the same names.  If you deploy the exes to separate folders or keep them in separate folders it will work either way.

I would even go further and look how you can break the application up further into more assemblies/dlls as it will give you even more flexibility.  I would also have a single File for AssemblyInfo, and Add it as a linked file to all your projects.  This means you have have a single version across all your dlls/exes.
http://vsh.infozerk.net/options/add-an-existing-file-to-a-project-without-copying-it/

Comment: Is it true that the assembly GUID has nothing to do with the function of a DLL if we do not expose it to COM?  The assembly info file has a reference to the GUID.  So having this file in common would mean that this GUID is common across all components in the project.

Comment: Its fine and is done all the time.  There are lots of common .net Libraries that are deployed on your PC all the time.  For some of the thirdy party libries, Telerik, componentone, other random opensource dlls will be in many different locations on your pc.  The same assemblies (on the same version and different  versions) will installed with different applications all over your pc.  Each .net Application is separate.